# Get rowIndex = -1 in Chrome. In IE, FF works fine

Tags: google-chrome, html-table

I would like for first row and column of cells to be assigned a letter and a digit (like an excel table), with rows (cell.cellIndex == 0), no problems it's working fine, but for every column (row.rowIndex == 0 && cell.cellIndex != 0) it works only in browsers IE and FF, in Chrome it's not working. It gets a rowIndex = -1

```
for (var i = 0; i <= inpRow.value; i++) {
    array[i] = new Array();
    arrayFunc[i] = new Array();
    row = document.createElement('tr')
    table.appendChild(row);
    for (var j = 0; j <= inpCol.value; j++) {
        cell = document.createElement('td');
        row.appendChild(cell);
        cell.setAttribute('id', (i) + "." + (j));
        if (row.rowIndex == 0 && cell.cellIndex != 0) { // row.rowIndex in chrome gets -1
                if ((j-1) >= 26) { // j-1 to asign letter from the second cell
                    var tmp = (j-1) / 26;
                    for (var f = 0; f < parseInt(tmp, 10) ; f++) {
                        for (var k = 0; k <= (j-1) - (26 * parseInt(tmp, 10)) ; k++) {
                            cell.innerHTML = '<b>' + String.fromCharCode(f + 65) + String.fromCharCode(k + 65) + '</b>';
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    cell.innerHTML = '<b>' + String.fromCharCode(j + 64) + '</b>';
                }
            cell.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
        } else if (cell.cellIndex == 0) {
            cell.innerHTML = '<b>' + i + '</b>';
            cell.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
        }
 }
```

I have alternative variant using not row and cell Index, but using id:

```
cell.id.substr(0, 1) == '0' && cell.id != '0.0'
```

and it works fine in all browsers, but i would like to use cell and row Index:

```
row.rowIndex == 0 && cell.cellIndex != 0
```

[Full code](http://jsfiddle.net/a7pMn/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like both Chrome and Safari assign a row index of -1 to each row you append to a table using the "document.createElement('tr');" approach. Then there is no point searching for or comparing rows by index since each row is simply -1.

Instead of the following 2 lines just before the start of you 2nd for loop:

```
row = document.createElement('tr')
table.appendChild(row);
```

use:

`row = table.insertRow(-1);`

This should do exactly the same job, but Chrome and Safari will now insert correct indexes for each row.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in the [Webkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) layout engine, (that moved to the forked [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(layout_engine)) engine as well). This is why it works well in Firefox but not in Chrome (Blink) or Safari (Webkit).

The bug is reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=495884).